# Recognizability and complements

Tags: turing-machines, undecidability

I'm learning about Turing Machines, decidability, and recognizability, and read that if a language is recognizable, its complement is *sometimes* recognizable. I don't really understand how this could be, can someone give me an example where a language has a recognizable complement and an unrecognizable complement? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example 1.**
The empty language is recognizable and its complement (the language containing all the words) is also recognizable.

**Example 2.**
Any [regular language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) is recognizable and, since regular languages are [closed under complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language#Closure_properties), its complement is also recognizable.

**Example 3.**
The language $H = \{ \langle T, x \rangle : T \mbox{ is a Turing Machine}, x \in \{0,1\}^*, T(x) \mbox{ halts}\}$ is recognizable.
In order to recognize $H$ it suffices to build a Turing machine $M$ that checks if  $T$ is a valid description of a Turing machine, simulates $T$ on $x$ until $T(x)$ halts (possibly forever), and accepts.

The complement $\overline{H}$ of $H$, however, is not recognizable as if it was recognizable a Turing machine $M'$ for $\overline{H}$, together with $M$, would allow to solve the [Halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). To do so simply simulate in parallel $M$ and $M'$ until one of them accepts.